# PDT/PHP plugin in Eclipse in Ubuntu not working - “page not found” error

Tags: php, linux, eclipse, plugins, ubuntu

I am not having success getting the PDT (PHP Development Tools, SDK 2.0.2 and 2.1.2) plugin to work in Eclipse in Ubuntu 11.04. I encounter the following page when attempting to run a php file:

`Not Found`

The requested URL /TestPHP/tester.php was not found on this server. Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80"

When I navigate to 127.0.0.1:8000/TestPHP/tester.php, I see the code in the tester.php file rendered as text, where it's not actually interpreting the code but directly printing it.

Here is the procedure I followed from installation to attempted execution: Install Eclipse -> Install PDT 2.1.2/2.0.2 -> Install Lamp using Tasksel install -> Add ServerName localhost in confd file -> Start Eclipse -> Open PHP Perspective -> Create new PHP project -> Create new PHP file -> run file with "Run as PHP Web Page" on the sub-menu for the Run button.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the PHP module is not enabled in your Lamp installation. If you'd be using Ubuntu's Apache & PHP packages, you could try to run: `a2enmod php5` on the shell.